# How to include views in ServiceStack.OrmLite T4

Tags: database, t4, ormlite-servicestack

The T4 for generating DB Poco files was updated and I see an [IncludeViews](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/T4/OrmLite.Core.ttinclude#L89) variable. However I don't see how to modify this without changing the ttinclude file.

Is that the expected solution? On every update would I need to re-change the variable?